# Foreach loop missing results when run

Tags: powershell

Im running a script to query the drives of servers to bring back disk space results. The script runs using a text file list of servers for this question i only has one server name in the txt file and ultimately builds a html document.

The problem arises because when i use the 3rd example of this script - it will not bring back the correct number of drives for the server.
So in order to test this i did the following:

**Test 1.**

```
Get-WmiObject 
    -ComputerName DB-server01 
    -Class Win32_LogicalDisk 
    -Filter "DriveType = 3"
```

**Result:**

```
DeviceID     : C:
DriveType    : 3
ProviderName : 
FreeSpace    : 28575797248
Size         : 146056146944
VolumeName   : OS

DeviceID     : V:
DriveType    : 3
ProviderName : 
FreeSpace    : 814725959680
Size         : 898316103680
VolumeName   : SQLData

DeviceID     : W:
DriveType    : 3
ProviderName : 
FreeSpace    : 293852868608
Size         : 299436601344
VolumeName   : SQLLogs
```

**Test 2.**

```
$computers = Get-Content "C:\Powershell\servers.txt";
write-host $computers
foreach($computer in $computers)
{ 
    $disks = Get-WmiObject 
        -ComputerName $computer 
        -Class Win32_LogicalDisk 
        -Filter "DriveType = 3"
    write-host $disks
}
```

**Result**

DB-server01

\DB-server01\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="C:" \db- server01\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="V:" \db-server01\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="W:"

**Test 3.**

```
$i = 0;
$percentWarning = 90;
$percentCritcal = 25;
$computers = Get-Content "C:\Powershell\servers.txt";
write-host $computers

foreach($computer in $computers)
{ 
    $disks = Get-WmiObject 
        -ComputerName $computer 
        -Class Win32_LogicalDisk 
        -Filter "DriveType = 3"

    $computer = $computer.toupper()

    foreach($disk in $disks)
    {        
        $deviceID = $disk.DeviceID;
        $volName = $disk.VolumeName;
        [float]$size = $disk.Size;
        [float]$freespace = $disk.FreeSpace; 
        $percentFree = [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100, 2);
        $sizeGB = [Math]::Round($size / 1073741824, 2);
        $freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round($freespace / 1073741824, 2);
        $usedSpaceGB = $sizeGB - $freeSpaceGB;

        $color = $whiteColor;

        if($percentFree -lt $percentWarning)      
        {
            $color = $greenColor
            if($percentFree -lt $percentCritcal)
            {
                $color = $redColor
            }        

            if ($percentFree -eq "NaN")
            {
                $PercentFree = "N/A"
                $Color = $whiteColor
            }  

            Add-Content $diskReport $dataRow;

            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 
                "$computer $deviceID percentage free space = $percentFree";

            $i++  
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
DB-Server01 C: percentage free space = 19.56
```

When run through the look test 3 only brings back drive c and missed V & W.

???????

Comment: Ive actually realised why this is happening - this was due to the $percentWarning = 90; $percentCritcal = 25; Both of which where telling the output only to succeed if a drive had less than 90% free - some servers had much higher space free value and certainly this one did - so it wasnt reporting on that drive.  Ive since edited the value to be 99% and its picking up all drives again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that indeed the disks were not shown because the script was skipping disks that have plenty disk space. If you want all the disks shown, then script has to be adjusted. The problem is that a "}" isn't placed correctly for the disks without problems to turn up.
The script was only printing if the percentage is lower then the warning level

You could change the last bit to :

```
    if($percentFree -lt $percentWarning)      
    {
        $color = $greenColor
        if($percentFree -lt $percentCritcal)
        {
            $color = $redColor
        }        

        if ($percentFree -eq "NaN")
        {
            $PercentFree = "N/A"
            $Color = $whiteColor
        }  }

        Add-Content $diskReport $dataRow;

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 
            "$computer $deviceID percentage free space = $percentFree";

        $i++  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ive actually realised why this is happening - this was due to the

$percentWarning = 90;

Of which where telling the output only to succeed if a drive had less than 90% free - some servers had much higher space free value and certainly this one did - so it wasnt reporting on that drive. Ive since edited the value to be 99% and its picking up all drives again